# A polynomial equality problem

Tags: polynomials, products

$a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n,a_{n+1}$ are fixed real numbers in $(-1,\infty)$.

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are fixed real numbers in $(0,1)$.

Is it possible to prove that there exists or doesn't exists a real number $x_3$ in $(0,1)$ such that

$$\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_3a_i) = \frac{1}{2}\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_1a_i) + \frac{1}{2}\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_2a_i)$$

**and**

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1 + x_3a_i) = \frac{1}{2}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1 + x_1a_i) + \frac{1}{2}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1 + x_2a_i)$$

or is it possible to prove that this problem is unsolvable to begin with?

Comment: For $n=1$ the two equations imply that $x_1=x_2.$ So in general it isn't solvable... I've been looking at larger $n$ and so far it looks complicated, but unlikely that there be such $x_3$ for an arbitrary set of $a_k$ and choice of $x_1,x_2.$

Answer (score 1):

If there is a simultaneous solution, then either $a_{n+1}=0$ or it must be
$$
x_3=\frac{x_1\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_1a_i) + x_2\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_2a_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_1a_i) + \prod_{i=1}^n (1 + x_2a_i)}.
$$
That this is actually also a solution of the first $n$-th degree polynomial is highly unlikely.

Comment: i'll accept this if there is no formal proof after one or two months, but you're right, it's really unlikely!